# save user input to database using contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql

[image]

I have a profile page consisting of two people. I want users to be able to edit the name section, job title, and description and store the data into a database, but im running into issues doing that with "contenteditable" tag.

Also I would like for users to be able to click the pictures and have the ability to change the image and save to database.

```css
:root {
    font-size: 10px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #262626;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.container {
  
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 93.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: 0.5rem auto #4d90fe;
}

.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

/* Profile Section */

.profile {
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

.profile::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


.profile-user-settings,
.profile-stats,
.profile-bio {
    float: left;
    width: calc(66.666% - 2rem);
}

.profile-user-settings {
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
}

.profile-user-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-edit-btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    border: 0.1rem solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    padding: 0 2.4rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}





.profile-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.profile-stats li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}



.profile-real-name,
.profile-stat-count,
.profile-edit-btn {
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Gallery Section */

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: -1rem -1rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.gallery-item {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 22rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-item-info,
.gallery-item:focus .gallery-item-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.gallery-item-info {
    display: none;
}

.gallery-item-info li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.gallery-item-likes {
    margin-right: 2.2rem;
}

.gallery-item-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.fa-clone,
.fa-comment {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.gallery-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}



/* Media Query */

@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
    .profile {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 4rem 0;
    }

    .profile::after {
        display: none;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    .profile-user-settings {
        flex-basis: calc(100% - 10.7rem);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-user-name {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        order: 1;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .profile-bio {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    .profile-stats {
        order: 1;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-stats ul {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1.2rem 0;
        border-top: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
        border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
    }

    .profile-stats li {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .profile-stat-count {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Spinner Animation */

@keyframes loader {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

/*

The following code will only run if your browser supports CSS grid.

Remove or comment-out the code block below to see how the browser will fall-back to flexbox & floated styling. 

*/

@supports (display: grid) {
    .profile {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-column-gap: 3rem;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .profile-image {
        grid-row: 1 / -1;
    }

    .gallery {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(22rem, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 2rem;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-stats,
    .profile-bio,
    .gallery-item,
    .gallery {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 40rem) {
        .profile {
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
        }

        .profile-image {
            grid-row: 1 / 2;
        }

        .profile-user-settings {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }

        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-stats,
        .profile-bio {
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }

        .profile-user-settings,
        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-settings-btn,
        .profile-bio,
        .profile-stats {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200,300,800);
@import url(https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css);
figure.snip0056 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 380px;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip0056 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
figure.snip0056 > img {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
  transform: scale(1.6);
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: -15%;
  z-index: 1;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption {
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2,
figure.snip0056 figcaption p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption h2 span {
  font-weight: 800;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption .icons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption .icons i {
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption a {
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
figure.snip0056 figcaption a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
figure.snip0056 .position {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 1;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  clear: both;
}
figure.snip0056.blue .position {
  background: #20638f;
}
figure.snip0056.red .position {
  background: #962d22;
}
figure.snip0056.yellow .position {
  background: #bf6516;
}
figure.snip0056:hover > img,
figure.snip0056.hover > img {
  right: -12%;
}
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

#social {
  position: absolute;
  right:    0;
  bottom:   0;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.smGlobalBtn { /* global button class */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border:2px solid #ddd; /* add border to the buttons */
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #999;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 27px;
    -moz-border-radius:27px;
    -webkit-border-radius:27px;
}

/* facebook button class*/
.facebookBtn{
    background: #4060A5;
}

.facebookBtn:before{ /* use :before to add the relevant icons */
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f09a"; /* add facebook icon */
}

.facebookBtn:hover{
    color: #4060A5;
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #4060A5; /* change the border color on mouse hover */
}

/* twitter button class*/
.twitterBtn{
    background: #00ABE3;
}

.twitterBtn:before{
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      content: "\f099"; /* add twitter icon */
      
}

.twitterBtn:hover{
      color: #00ABE3;
      background: #fff;
      border-color: #00ABE3;
}


/* instagram button class*/
.instagramBtn{
    background: #4169E1;
}

.instagramBtn:before{
      font-family: "FontAwesome";
      content: "\f16d"; /* add instagram icon */
}

.instagramBtn:hover{
      color: #00FFFF;
      background: #fff;
      border-color: #4169E1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

   <div class="profile">

     <h1 contenteditable="true">janedoe_</h1>

     <button class="btn profile-edit-btn">Edit Profile</button>

   </div>
   <!-- End of profile section -->

 </div>
 <!-- End of container -->

 </header>

 <main>

   <div class="container">
     <figure class="snip0056">
       <figcaption>
         <h3 contenteditable="true">Stuart <span>White</span></h3>
       <h2><p contenteditable="true">I suppose if we couldn't laugh at things that don't make sense, we couldn't react to a lot of life.</h2></p>
         
       </figcaption><img class="image1" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample8.jpg" alt="profilepic1" />
        
      <div class="position"><h3 contenteditable="true">Web Designer</div></h3>
     </figure>
     <figure class="snip0056 yellow">
       <figcaption>
         <h3 contenteditable="true">Diana <span>Reed</span></h3>
        <h2> <p contenteditable="true">The only skills I have patience to learn are those that have no real application in life.</h2></p>
         
       </figcaption><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample9.jpg" alt="sample9" />
        <div class="position"><h3 contenteditable="true">Sales Manager</div></h3>
     </figure>
<div id="social">
<a class="facebookBtn smGlobalBtn" href="https://facebook.com/ngurah.dimas.94" ></a>
<a class="twitterBtn smGlobalBtn" href="https://twitter.com/ngurahdimas" ></a>
  
<a class="instagramBtn smGlobalBtn" href="http://instagram.com/ngurahdimas_" ></a>
      </div>
   
 </main>
```

Comment: What issues are you running into? You'll need to extract all the `textContent` values of each element and send that to the database. It would be a lot easier to use a form to fill in, both from a practicality as a user experience standpoint.

Comment: my issue is that i dont know how to extract the values to the database. two questions first, how would i even extract the values and send to the database? second if i used a form to accomplish this would it not mess up the description inside the figcaption? sorry if i sound dumb

Comment: Well for one, a `<form>` element with `<input>` elements make it incredibly easy to extract these values as that is the purpose of those elements. Secondly, it doesn't have to mess up anything. Just a little CSS magic and you can make an `input` or `textarea` look like a normal div. And it would be good UX to indicate to the user that the content can be edited. Then all you have to do is to submit the form and you got your values on the server.

Comment: Thank you very much